Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'semantic_kernel.skill', Python, AzureOpenAI
While trying to run the code for creating basic agents in Python using Semantic Kernel, it is giving ModuleNotFoundError:

No module named 'semantic_kernel.skill'.

Facing the same error for semantic_kernel.skill_definition as well.
Referred to 4777 but the hyperlink to the "Example" provided in that issue is giving 404 error.
As per my knowledge, there is no executable code for Agents using Semantic Kernel in Python. Please share the resources if you have any.
To reproduce: execute the below code:
import os
import semantic_kernel as sk
from semantic_kernel.connectors.ai.open_ai import AzureTextCompletion
from semantic_kernel.skill import Skill
from semantic_kernel.skill import sk_function
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
from azure.search.documents.models import QueryType

# Initialize the Semantic Kernel
kernel = sk.Kernel()

# Register Azure OpenAI text completion service
azure_text_completion = AzureTextCompletion(
    endpoint=AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT,
    api_key=AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
    deployment_name=DEPLOYMENT_NAME
)
kernel.register_service("text-completion", azure_text_completion)

# Initialize Azure Cognitive Search client
search_client = SearchClient(
    endpoint=AZURE_SEARCH_ENDPOINT,
    index_name=AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME,
    credential=AzureKeyCredential(AZURE_SEARCH_API_KEY)
)

# Define a simple skill
class GreetingSkill(Skill):
    @sk_function
    def say_hello(self, name: str) -> str:
        return f"Hello, {name}!"

# Define a search skill
class SearchSkill(Skill):
    @sk_function
    def search_documents(self, query: str) -> str:
        results = search_client.search(search_text=query, query_type=QueryType.SIMPLE)
        response = [doc['content'] for doc in results]
        return '\n'.join(response)

# Register the skills with the kernel
greeting_skill = GreetingSkill()
search_skill = SearchSkill()

kernel.register_skill("GreetingSkill", greeting_skill)
kernel.register_skill("SearchSkill", search_skill)

# Define a function to interact with the AI agent
def interact_with_agent(kernel, skill_name, function_name, **kwargs):
    result = kernel.execute(skill_name, function_name, **kwargs)
    return result

# Example interaction with the AI agent
result = interact_with_agent(kernel, "GreetingSkill", "say_hello", name="Alice")
print(result)  # Output: Hello, Alice!

# Example search interaction with the AI agent
search_result = interact_with_agent(kernel, "SearchSkill", "search_documents", query="Azure Cognitive Services")
print(search_result)  # Output: Search results related to "Azure Cognitive Services"


OS: [e.g. Windows, Mac] - Windows
IDE: [e.g. Visual Studio, VS Code] - VS Code
I have raised a GitHub issue as well.
I tried executing the above code and I'm expecting an error free code execution.

have you installed semantic-kernel? check pip show semantic-kernel

Yes. But no luck
